# Sharper Google Maps Circles for mobile devices

Tags: google-maps-api-3, webview, geometry, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm building an android app that uses a webview to show a google maps canvas (javascript api v3). (Using a webview to do this for reasons). I am adding some [circles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) to this map, on specific locations, from a database.

The problem is; the circles are not as sharp as on a "regular" screen.
See this screenshot: http://imgdump.nl/hosted/7ce8360c83a3889cdc30abfbb7d3cd72.png

I tried scaling and zooming using css, with different but unsatisfying results.

Is there a way to render these circles for mobile screens with a higher pixel density? Or any other solutions for this problem?

Thanks,

Stef

Comment: You mentioned the webview and reasons. What are they? This is likely related with the webview but I am no Android expert.

Comment: I'm using appcelerator's Titanium to build this app. Unlike titanium's map module, the google maps javascript api allows me to draw circles around markers on the map, with a certain radius in meters. And besides the drawing, a lot of other features that are useful to this app, which are hard/complex to code in titanium (and since there's a deadline...). Also at this moment there is some weird bug in the titanium map module, since google updated play services.

Comment: Then I suggest you tag your question with the appropriate titanium and webview tags, and you might get people that know about it to have a look at your question...